# how to get id value which is inside a another class?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a BMR calculator but i am not able to get the id value. the code is attached below.

..

```
        <div class="bmr">
            <form>
            <label for="age" id="age1">Enter your Age </label>
                <input id="age" type="text" value="" style="width: 180px; height: 30px"><br>
            <label for="weight" id="weight1">Weight (in KG)</label>
                <input id="weight" type="text" value="" style="width: 180px; height: 30px"><br>
                <input type="radio" id="gender" class="male1">Male
                <input type="radio" id="gender">Female<br>
            <label for="height" id="height1">Enter your height in cm</label>
                <input type="text" id="height" style="width: 180px; height: 30px"><br>
            <button type="button" id="submit" onClick="calculatebmr()">Calculate</button>


            </form>
            </div>
```

javascript code is

```
function calculatebmr(){

var age = Document.getElementById("age").value;
var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
alert(age);
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Look at your browser console.  Observe the error message.  `Document` is not the same thing as `document`, as JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

//Do this one!

```
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
```

Console.log(age,weight); // see result

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
alert(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculatebmr(){

  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;

  alert(age);
}
```

Your code was correct, only Document you have written was wrong. It should be `document.getElementById`

Hope it'll help